# Number of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ that satisfy a certain property

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

Let $S(n,p)=\{a\in \mathbb{Z}_p : a^n=1$ (mod $p$)$\}$ where $p\geq3$ is a prime number and $1\leq n\leq p$. I am interested in finding a general formula for cardinality of $S(n,p)$. For example, I know that $|S(1,p)|=1$ and $|S(p-1,p)|=p-1$ (by Fermat's little theorem).

Comment: Ask yourself, is this a subgroup of $(\Bbb Z_p)^{\ast}$?

Comment: It is just $n $ as long as $n $ divides $p-1$ and 0 else. This is because the units mod $p $ form a cyclic group.

Comment: What do you mean by 0? Its cardinality can't be zero because 1 is always there.

Comment: Woops, brain fart. You are right.

Comment: Indeed, only the first part was right. One needs to think for just a few extra seconds to get the full picture (I forgot to do this).

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times = \{ 1,2,\dots,p-1 \}$ form a group under multiplication modulo $p$. Since $p$ is prime, this group is cyclic.

In a cyclic group of order $n$, the number of elements of order $k$ is $\varphi(k)$ if $k$ divides $n$ (and 0 otherwise) where $\varphi(k)$ is [Euler's Totient Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Next, $x^n \equiv 1$ (mod $p$) iff the order of $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ is divisible by $n$. So $|S(n,p)|$ is the number of elements of orders dividing $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$.

This means that 
$$|S(n,p)| = \sum \varphi(k)$$
where the sum is over all $k$ that divide both $n$ and $p-1$ (the order of $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times = \{ 1,2,\dots,p-1 \}$). This means that $k$ ranges over the divisors of $\mathrm{gcd}(n,p-1)$.

Finally, a theorem of Gauss states that $\sum\limits_{d \mbox{ divides } \ell} \varphi(d)=\ell$.

Therefore, $|S(n,p)|=\mathrm{gcd}(n,p-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Already this has been answered. But I'd like to make two points: as $0$ is ruled out we are looking at a subset of the group $\mathbf{Z}_p^*$. And $x\mapsto x^n$ is a homomorphism of this group, and so the solution set $S(n,p)$ you are looking for is the kernel of that homomorphism.